# Django application 504 error after saving model

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django website running Django 1.8 with Python 3.4 and hosted on AWS via ElasticBeanstalk.

Recently, I've been having some issues with the Django admin area and 504 errors. The problem is very difficult to reproduce, it seems to happen randomly.

When I save an instance of a model, sometimes the website hangs and returns a 504 error (and doesn't save). Afterwhich elasticbeanstalk restarts the server and everything works fine again.

In my logs I get the following errors.

```
End of script output before headers: wsgi.py

extern "Python": function Cryptography_rand_bytes() called, but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.
```

These two errors are repeated multiple times. Can anyone help me figure out how I can debug this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It is probably due to this bug 
https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2299

How to fix discussed here
https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2473

Which seems to say uninstall python Cryptography library and then pip install version 1.1 of it

Comment: Can you provide any details on how I can achieve that (uninstall cryptography library and reinstall version 1.1) using beanstalk? I can put the cryptography library in my requirements.txt file to install via PIP, but not sure how to uninstall first. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like this fixed the problem. I updated cryptography and today I'm dealing with the same exact issue.

Comment: @abz101 were you able to solve this issue? I have a different server setup but am experiencing the same error message in my logs so maybe your solution could help with some guidance in the right direction.

Comment: @abz101 did you ever get around to solving this?

Comment: No. I just launched an additional instance with Elastic BeanStalk and use load balancing to just direct users to the "healthy" instance. With EBS, when an instance goes down, it restarts automatically, so it starts working automatically. But this is not a solution, just a temporary fix until I can figure out what is going on.... please report back if you have any info.

Answer (score 0):

This error showed up for me by django-ses calling for the rate limit through boto's make_request in the connections module. Reverting cryptography 1.5 to 1.1 fixed my errors.