# 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'resolve' when using Google Compute Engine

Tags: python, django, cryptography, google-compute-engine

I have an issue related to Cryptography package in Python. Can you please help in resolving these, if possible ? (tried a lot, but couldnt figure out the exact solution)

The python code which initiates this error:

```
print("Salt: %s" % salt)
server_key = pyelliptic.ECC(curve="prime256v1")  # ----->> Line2
print("Server_key: %s" % server_key)   # ----->> Line3
server_key_id = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(server_key.get_pubkey()[1:])

http_ece.keys[server_key_id] = server_key
http_ece.labels[server_key_id] = "P-256"
encrypted = http_ece.encrypt(data, salt=salt, keyid=server_key_id,
            dh=self.receiver_key, authSecret=self.auth_key)  # ----->> Line8
```

Value of "Salt" is getting displayed in 100% of the cases.

If **Line3** gets executed successfully, I see the the following EntryPoint Error because of http_ece.encrypt() call (**Line8**):

```
AttributeError("'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'resolve'",)
```

(Ref. File Link: [https://github.com/martinthomson/encrypted-content-encoding/blob/master/python/http_ece/init.py#L128](https://github.com/martinthomson/encrypted-content-encoding/blob/master/python/http_ece/__init__.py#L128) )

Requirements.txt(partial):

```
cryptography==1.5
pyelliptic==1.5.7
pyOpenSSL==16.1.0
```

On Running the command: `sudo pip freeze --all |grep setuptools`, I get:
`setuptools==27.1.2`

Please let me know if any more detail is required.

This problem seems to be basically due to some Old/Incompatible packages(related to PyElliptic, Cryptography, PyOpenSSL and/or setuptools) installed on the VM. For Reference: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3149

Can someone please suggest a good solution to resolve this issue completely ?

Thanks,

Comment: what is the version of pyelliptic?

Comment: pyelliptic==1.5.7, cryptography==1.5

Comment: next, what is the implementation and version of openssl?

Comment: pyOpenSSL==16.1.0. I am basically trying to encrypt web push notification data.  (The same set of packages seems to be working fine on Local Server but not on Google Compute Engine VM)

Comment: what is the openssl implementation on that VM? I am not talking of pyOpenSSL but the system library that came from yum or apt

Comment: @e4c5 Updated Python Code Snippet. I am not sure about how to check the openssl implementation on the VM. Any pointers for this ?

Comment: Include the relevant parts of stacktrace with the error messages, they are almost useless without it unless one manages to reproduce your problem (which is nigh-impossible as we don't know what triggers it).

Comment: Besides, what's an "intermediate error"? In Python, an exception is typically either caught and handled (thus not manifesting itself), or terminates the execution.

Comment: These are the complete messages which I can see on the console. For example: if you look at https://github.com/yann2192/pyelliptic/blob/master/pyelliptic/ecc.py#L214 and see the return value, the same value is specified here. Is there any other way to get the complete stack trace ? (Renamed "Intermediate Error")

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev This problem is basically due to some wrong/incomplete/old packages installed on the VM. For Reference: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2838

Comment: Since you never gave the traceback for the error in title, I'm forced to guess.

Comment: these are the complete errors I got on my console. Had there been any line(or even character) extra on the console, I would have happily shared it over here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran Following Commands from the project path /opt/projects/myproject-google/myproject and it resolved the Attribute EntryPoint Error Issue:

(Assuming project virtual env path as: /opt/projects/myproject-google/venv)

Command: (from path: /opt/projects/myproject-google/myproject)

```
export PYTHONPATH=      # [Blank]
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv setuptools
sudo rm -rf ../venv
sudo virtualenv ../venv
source ../venv/bin/activate
sudo pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
deactivate
```

Running the above commands upgraded the  virtual environment & the setuptools version inside the virtual Env. located at path:  /opt/projects/myproject-google/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages. To test if setuptools have upgraded successfully, try some of these commands:

1. **Command**: `sudo virtualenv --version`
   **Output**: `15.0.3`
2. **Command**: `echo $PYTHONPATH`
   **Output**: [blank]
3. **Command**: `python -c 'import pkg_resources; print(pkg_resources.__file__)'`
   **Output**: `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc`
4. **Command**: `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`
   **Output**: `['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/opt/projects/myproject-google/myproject', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat']`
5. **Command**: `ls  /opt/projects/myproject-google/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
   **Output**:
   `easy_install.py   pip                  pkg_resources  setuptools-27.2.0.dist-info  wheel-0.30.0a0.dist-info
   easy_install.pyc  pip-8.1.2.dist-info  setuptools     wheel`
6. **Command**: `python -c 'from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend; print(default_backend())'`
   **Output**: `<cryptography.hazmat.backends.multibackend.MultiBackend object at 0x7ff83a838d50>`
7. **Command** `/opt/projects/myproject-google/venv/bin/python -c 'from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend; print(default_backend())'`
   **Output**

   `Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.backends`
8. **Command**: `/opt/projects/myproject-google/venv/bin/python -c "import pkg_resources; print(pkg_resources.__file__)"`
   **Output**: `/opt/projects/myproject-google/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.pyc`

Ref Link: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3149

These Steps resolved the Attribute EntryPoint Issue completely with an updated version of cryptography package & the setuptools.

**Update** As on 15 September 2016, The Cryptography Team has again added the workaround for supporting old packages too.
(Ref. Link: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3150 )

Answer (score 3):

The [issue](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2838) referenced in [c66303382](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413987/entrypoint-object-has-no-attribute-resolve-when-using-google-compute-engine?noredirect=1#comment66303382_39413987) has this traceback (you never gave your traceback so I have to assume yours ends the same way):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 35, in default_backend
    _default_backend = MultiBackend(_available_backends())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 22, in _available_backends
    "cryptography.backends"
```

[The full line](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/1a6628e55126ec1c98c98a46c04f777f77eff934/src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py#L19-L24) that triggers the error looks like this:

```
_available_backends_list = [
        ep.resolve()
        for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(
            "cryptography.backends"
        )
    ]
```

Searching the [repository](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools) for `EntryPoint` definition, then [blaming `pkg_resources/__init__.py`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blame/master/pkg_resources/__init__.py#L2260) where it is reveals that `pkg_resources.EntryPoint.resolve()` was added in [commit 92a553d3adeb431cdf92b136ac9ccc3f2ef98bf1](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/commit/92a553d3adeb431cdf92b136ac9ccc3f2ef98bf1) (2015-01-05) that went into `setuptools v11.3`.

Thus you'll see this error if you use an older version.

Comment: yes, this is the issue for one of the Errors (Attribute 'EntryPoint'). But the Cryptography team has again replaced this code back to support old versions. Ref. Link: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3150

Comment: @Naveen they have... _10 hours ago._

Comment: @Naveen the other errors are a completely unrelated matter. At first glance, the first part of the first message is produced by `pyelliptic.ECC._generate()`. But, it throws an exception with that message! If your program doesn't terminate as a result, this means somthing else up the stack - possibly in your own code - masks the error - which is in general not a good thing to do. I cannot find the source of the `error:00000000<...>` part, this may be your code, so you'd better debug and/or search your codebase for this.

Comment: @Naveen the 2nd message seems to be covered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546513/django-application-504-error-after-saving-model

Comment: I see. I didn't trust your source links (you didn't explicitly state which version you use, so it could be anything) and ended up looking at an older version of the code.

Comment: Anyway, this is irrelevant to the problem in title - which has been resolved - so [this should go into a separate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).